# Multi Linear Regression on String Values

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, one-hot-encoding

I'm using datasets which involves mostly of string values. The main outcome of the project is that it should predict success. Now I can use OneHotEncoding to convert string values in numerical format but the values are a lot.  I'm using Multi Linear Regression and the only numerical value is of the output which is supposed to be predicted by my model.

1. Query 1:
   By using sklearn, when encoding the string values, should it not take the whole resources as there are a lot of values ?
2. Query 2 :
   Will my model work if the independant values are in string format and the dependant value is in numerical format ? Like should it need some independant values in numerical format or string format is just fine ?
3. Query 3 :
   Is there any other and better way to use instead of OneHotEncoding ?

Explanation:
I'm trying to use IMDb datasets to predict the success of movie using movie's cast, producers, genres and some other variables. There are almost 5-6 independant variables used. and the dependant variable used are the ratings of the movies

Comment: You can leave your predictor output from OneHotEncoding. They are essentially dummy variables.  But be careful if you have a lot of predictors.  I don't know the size of your dataset or how many variables will be used in prediction.

Comment: datasets contains 100k+ rows and variables will be 5-6 which will be used in predicting

Comment: That's not a lot of variables.  but, since you will be using linear regression it is still sensitive to the strict assumptions

Comment: I don't think linear regression is the best model in your case, Please add more information about your features, like what do those strings represent? how many unique values are there in each feature? is success a binary variable?

Comment: No, output value will be a continuous value as it will be the rating of the movie. Can you suggest any other way of doing it if multi linear regression is not suitable in this scenerio?

Comment: i'd suggest to onehot encode your dataset and use tree based models, they perform way better than distance-based models like linear regression.